# C++ Virtual Destructors

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

When creating **prototype classes** I lay out the destructor as such:

```
virtual ~MyClass();
```

When finalizing the class in a library I noticed that I cannot add 'virtual'. Is this normal, and is virtual taken into consideration or am I do something wrong?

For example; when I try to do this I get a compiler error:

```
virtual MyClass::~MyClass() { }
```

Instead doing this works:

```
MyClass::~MyClass() { }
```

My question is since I do not have to include `virtual` in the final code write of the destructor does the destructor still behave as a virtual destructor (since it is virtual as a prototype)?

Comment: Yay for C++ question number 0x8000 :)

Comment: @Fred:  I guess people are now asking questions about C++ _a bit more_ than before? ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `virtual` keyword is only used as part of the member function declaration inside of the class definition.

If the member function is defined outside of the class definition, the `virtual` keyword is not placed there.

Comment: That answered my question very nicely :)

Comment: @DeadMG you have to wait 15 minutes before marking an answer.

Comment: @m00st: Oh. I've never had a question answered that quickly.

Answer (score 4):

The virtual keyword can only be used on the function declarations within a class declaration (typically in a header file), not on the definitions within a source file. This is true for all functions, not just destructors.